# add the sku to the url key Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, simple-product, sku, url-key

I want to rewrite the url of product from

[www.example.com/product-name.html](http://www.example.com/product-name.html)

To

[www.example.com/SKU.html](http://www.example.com/SKU.html)

Someone can help me? The products we sell are unique, but share the same name. So when we add two different products with the same name, it throws back the error that that URL already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please created a custom module to override

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php

Where in `prepareProductUrlKey()`

From

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() : $urlKey);
```

To

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() . "-" . $product->getSku() : $urlKey);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Mayur, After changing the above code, existing product url key will work.

Comment: I checked this in local and it is working so give you.